# jQuery fadeIn animation display data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jQuery animation to display data.

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zp240znv/394/)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>List 1, Line 1</li>
    <li>List 1, Line 2</li>
    <li>List 1, Line 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>List 2, Line 1</li>
    <li>List 2, Line 2</li>
    <li>List 2, Line 3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>List 2, Line 1</li>
    <li>List 2, Line 2</li>
    <li>List 2, Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

I have 3 `ul`.

and here is the JS

```
var base_duration = 2000;
$('ul').each(function(i) {
    var li_count = $(this).children().length,
        hide_timeout = ((i+1) * base_duration * li_count);
    $(this).children().each(function(ii) {
        var li = $(this),
            show_timeout = (i * li_count * base_duration) + (ii * 
 base_duration);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            li.animate({left:0, opacity:1})
        }, show_timeout);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            li.animate({left:'100%', opacity:0})
        }, hide_timeout);
    });
});
```

My question is, how to make duration when the data fade in (as you can see on demo, it shows so fast)?

Comment: Isn't it a basic duration?

Comment: Just add **duration** according to your requirements

Comment: Nice question with very clean coding.+1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give `speed` of animation in `animate` function.

See example here : http://jsfiddle.net/vineeshmp/zp240znv/396/

```
$listItems.eq(index).animate({left:0, opacity:1},1000, function() {
    AnimateList($listItems, index+1, callback)
});
```

`speed` attribute Possible values: milliseconds (100, 1000, 5000, etc),"slow","fast"

Answer (score 1):

Try to amend like this.

```
$listItems.eq(index).animate({left:0, opacity:1}, 5000, function()
```